# Typoscript MegaMenu stopped working after update to 9.5

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-9.x

I have a MegaMenu on a page built with fluid and Typoscript.
It Builds a normal Menu for all Toplevel entries and then
builds the MegaMenu based on Content Elements that are placed in
Colpos 3 (always). This used to work till TYPO3 9.5 and just stopped.

Typoscript:

```
lib.MainNavigation = HMENU
lib.MainNavigation {
    ...
    1 = TMENU
    1 {
       ....
    }
    2 < .1
    2 {
        ....
        stdWrap.append = CONTENT
        stdWrap.append {
            table = tt_content
            select {
                pidInList.field = pid
                where = colPos=3
                languageField=sys_language_uid
            } 
            wrap = |
        } 
        ...
    }
}
```

Anyone with an Idea what the problem or changes could be?
i´ve already checked the changes and havent found anything :-(

Comment: I suspect the stricter language handling in 9.5. what results do you get without the line with `languageField`? does it work in no language or only only some?

Comment: Cheers Bernd, unfortunately it has no impact, there ist no output for the second level at all :-(

Comment: maybe you miss a `renderObj`? what if you insert an explicit 'renderObj' like `renderObj = TEXT`/ `renderObj.field = uid` / `renderObj.wrap = [|]` ?

Comment: the same :-( i´ll go with a newer approach now, and build the whole thing with Fluid :)

Comment: you may use the adinpanel to identify your query and see why it failed to get content, as the query would not contain much it might be a wrong value in `pid` (but then it should have worked never)

Comment: thanks for your help :) i´ve changed the menu to fluid-only now and it works as expected. But i will track down the reason for the not working menu and post an answer here if i find one :)